# HTML div tag positioning with CSS

Tags: css, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a form, which needs to be made more mobile friendly, I've managed to do it with the CSS, but it involves a lot of `@media (max-width: ;)` scenarios with the CSS.

On part of the form, I have a checkbox, with a `help-tip` next to it, when I scale the screen down, the `help-tip` moves closer to the left side of the screen, because it's using the left side of `body` to determine where on the screen it should be which means as the screen shrinks, the `help-tip` eventually overlaps the text. Is there a way to get the `div` that the `help-tip` is under, to use the `div` from the checkbox as it's distance calculator instead of the left side of the `body`? - so it stays a constant distance from the end of the checkbox rather than overlapping it.

p.s. I'm using ASP.net MVC 5, hence the different style of code in the HTML.

Code below: 
HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
   <div class="checkbox">
      <label>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Catering, new { @class ="checkbox" 
      })  Catering is required, <a href="~/Content/Files/Catering_Menu.pdf" 
      target="_blank"> Menu. </a></label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1">
   <div class="help-tip1">
     <p>Please state catering required and list any dietary requirements.</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
   Additional Info for Catering:<br />
   @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Cateringinfo, new { @class = "form-control", 
   cols = "80%", rows = 2 })
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.help-tip1{
    position:absolute;
    top:1px;
    left:-70%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #272449;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    line-height: 26px;
    cursor: default;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-sm-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
    .col-sm-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
    }
  .col-sm-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
```

Comment: This is not pure HTML, so please update your tags!

Comment: Create an additional wrapper div around the markup, make that position:relative; have .help-tip1 within that and relative to it.